# Is it possible to get a client's IP address from HTTP request header?

Tags: python, http, python-requests, request-headers, python-requests-html

I wonder if it is possible to get client's IP address from http request header using Python? I was working on a weather project, it would be very good if I could show weather info of his own location.

Comment: Are you using any server frameworks?

Comment: Short answer: **NO**, but the endpoint will retrieve your IP address from the [IP protocol](https://erg.abdn.ac.uk/users/gorry/course/inet-pages/ip.html) packets used to make the request.

Comment: [This image](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/diagrams/tcpipprotocols.png) will help you visualize the different layers and TCP/IP protocols

Answer (score 7):

if you are hosting a server, and have access to the HTTP headers, you can get the clients IPs from the following ways

taken from [a node.js package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-ip) that I use in my server applications:

> The user ip is determined by the following order:

1. X-Client-IP
2. X-Forwarded-For (Header may return multiple IP addresses in the format: "client IP, proxy 1 IP, proxy 2 IP", so we take the the first one.)
3. CF-Connecting-IP (Cloudflare)
4. Fastly-Client-Ip (Fastly CDN and Firebase hosting header when forwared to a cloud function)
5. True-Client-Ip (Akamai and Cloudflare)
6. X-Real-IP (Nginx proxy/FastCGI)
7. X-Cluster-Client-IP (Rackspace LB, Riverbed Stingray)
8. X-Forwarded, Forwarded-For and Forwarded (Variations of #2)

Comment: If you are using Nginx as a reverse proxy then you can use the X-Real-IP header. This header contains the original IP address of the client, before it was forwarded by Nginx.

To use the X-Real-IP header, you need to add the following directive to your Nginx configuration:

```proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;```

This will tell Nginx to set the X-Real-IP header to the IP address of the client, as seen by the Nginx server.

Once you have added this directive, you can get the client IP address in your backend application by checking the X-Real-IP header.

Answer (score 0):

If the request happens to contain `X-Forwarded-For`, `X-Real-IP` then you *might* get the client's actual IP address. However, most of the time, if a user doesn't want you to know their actual IP by using a proxy there is no way for a server to tell. And as the other comments pointed out, if you are only working on the HTTP layer it's impossible to get the IP address. The two headers I mentioned are usually only added to the request if you are using a reverse proxy/load balancer.

Comment: He's tagged this post with the requests module, which makes me think he's not talking from a server's perspective? In which case there's no way to get a client's IP when you are in fact yourself a client.

Comment: @CillianCollins the way the question was phrased and tagged makes me think the OP only means they were trying to get the data from an HTTP request using Python, instead of the requests package